# Would like to be able to automatically browse and search internet with Java no graphics

Tags: java, browser, urlconnection

I am having a hard time figuring out how to use Java to automatically perform tasks for me on the internet.  The issue is that when I search for this, I usually end up finding links to APIs such as Selenium and others.  But I want to navigate through sites without any graphics and without recording what I am doing (I want to do it all inside the code).  For those of you who were around in the old days, I want to automate web browsing very similar to browsing the internet with [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

So for example, say I went to Google, I would want to be able to return the search bar somehow, then set the text to something in particular.  Then, I would want to get the search button and change it's state to pressed.  Then I would want to be able to maneuver through the results.

So here is some dummy code explaining what I would like to be able to do:

```
 ExampleClass eClass = new ExampleClass("www.google.com");
 //The search button is the 5th component
 InternetButton button = (InternetButton)eClass.getComponent(5); 
 //Text Field is 2nd component
 InternetTextField textField  = (InternetTextField)eClass.getComponent(2); 
 textField.setText("stack overflow");
 button.setPressed(true);
```

This would search for stack overflow on Google, then I would look through results.

I have been searching and searching and cannot find anything.  I am looking for more of a tutorial or example of what I want to do.  If would assume that the Java SDK probably contains everything that I need to do this, but I can't seem to find any help on the topic.  I could just be searching for the wrong key words.

If anyone can give any advice, it would be much appreciated.  If I am just searching for the wrong thing, and you are a better Googler than me, post it.

I have tried a little with HttpURLConnection, HttpsURLConnection, URLConnection, etc, but it is very complex to write from scratch without an example or tutorial.  I can grab files with these but not maneuver through sites.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net)

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal" browser.

An [example taken from their page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html#Submitting_a_form) that comes close to what you would like to do

```java
@Test
public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("root");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have yet to give it a try but you could look into [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/):

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.